# How to retrive all data from selected document in firebase | flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to retrieve all fields related to a specific document in firebase.How can I do that?
I have attached my code below.

[image]
I can get all values by this way

```
return new Text(snapshot.data['brand']);
```

but i need to retrive them without calling by key.
is there any way to retrive all data into map or var ?
please help me to solve that

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ItemView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String docID123;

  const ItemView({ this.docID123}) ;

  @override
  _ItemViewState createState() => _ItemViewState();
}
String name123;
class _ItemViewState extends State<ItemView> {
  @override
  //String docuID = Widget.documentid;
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final  Map<String, Object>rcvdData = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    //docID = ${rcvdData['docuID'];}
    //String name123  = rcvdData[0];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Item Data'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(widget.docID123),
          getItems(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Widget getItems(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      //1597917013710
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('ads').document('1597917013710').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          //snapshot.data.toString();
          return new Text("Loading");
        }
        
        var userDocument = snapshot.data;
        String myname = snapshot.data.map.toString();
        //return new Text(snapshot.data['brand']);
        return new Text(myname);
      }
    );
}


Future getCatagory() async {
      var firestone = Firestore.instance;

      QuerySnapshot alldata = await firestone.collection("catagory_names/Vehicles").getDocuments();
      for(int i=0;i<alldata.documents.length;i++){
                        DocumentSnapshot snap = alldata.documents[i];
                        
                      }

      return  Text('12345');

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve all the data"?  Everything is right there in the snapshot in `snapshot.data`.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what your specific goal is, and what specifically you're stuck on.

Comment: hey,I need to get and show all data without calling thier key values such as snapshot.data['brand']....need to retrive keys and values.then show them

Comment: `snapshot.data` is just a `Map<string, dynamic>` as shown in the [API documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html).  You can iterate it just like any other Map in dart.

Comment: if it possible please make a note on how to access mentioned data in the image